# Facebook PHP sdk v5 - get UserPages

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I'm trying to get the UserPages (where he is admin or not) with the v5 PHP Facebook SDK.

I'm instantiate the Facebook variable.

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([/* . . . */]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['email', 'manage_page'];
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://{your-website}/login-callback.php', $permissions);

echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';

// callback blablabla

$_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

$fb->setDefaultAccessToken($accessToken);
```

After that I try to get the pages from the user like this:

```
$response = $fb->get('/me/accounts');
```

Who is giving me the pages, **but I don't know how to cast this in a "Page" Object** for get the likes, stats and other things.

I saw some thing like GraphePage, but I'm unable to create this with the `$response` variable.

**How can I get a Facebook page object?** Are the permissions good? Am I doing something wrong? What is the `$response` variable type?

Comment: you need to pass parameters you want like this /me?fields=email,name,gender

Comment: /me/accounts?fields=likes for a page ?

Comment: check this 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_batch_request

Comment: and this too
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user#Reading

Comment: thanks, I will take a look at this =)

Comment: /me?fields=email,name,gender => good job, it works

Comment: i added an answer to point that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to pass parameters like email,name and gender like this

```
$response = $fb->get('/me/fields?email,name,gender');
```

some of those needs permission to be able to use them like email for example you need to pass them like this

```
  $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(array('email'));
```

you shouldn't be guessing the parameters check [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user#Reading)